# .filter() does not affect type of array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

check this snippet:

```
interface Foo {
    id: string;
}

const fooFunc = (arr: Foo[]): Foo[] => arr
    .map((item: Foo): Foo | null => {
        const someCheck = true;

        if (someCheck) {
            return { id: '123' };
        }

        return null;
    })
    .filter((item: Foo | null) => item !== null);
```

Or click here for a TS Playground link to it: https://pnda.me/TSPlaygroundFilterExample

> Type `null` is not assignable to type `Foo`

It complains, that it cannot assign `null` to `Foo` which is true, BUT: I use `.filter()` to filter out all possible `null`s.

Why is TypeScript still complaining about this? And what can I do about it?

Removing the `.filter()` on the array has no effect.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7657